# Versatile data structure for combined statistics

Tags: dataset, statistics, algorithms

Not sure if this is Math, Stats or Data Science, but I figured I would post it here to get the site used.

As a programmer, when you have a system/component implemented, you might want to allow some performance monitoring. For example to query how often a function call was used, how long it took and so on. So typically you care about count, means/percentile, max/min and similiar statistics. This could be measurements since startup, but also a rolling average or window.

I wonder if there is a good data structure which can be updated efficiently concurrently which can be used as the source for most of those queries. For example having a ringbuffer of rollup-metrics (count, sum, min, max) over increasing periods of time and a background aggregate process triggered regularly.

The focus here (for me) is on in-memory data structures with limited memory consumption. (For other things I would use a RRD type of library).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're looking for, because it seems like a simple log of what and when is all you need.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz in that case I was looking for in-memory, but sure I can push the events to a logfile or redis or similiar. Then I still need datastructure(s) for the efficient calculations. I would like to combine the typical values in a way I dont have to have buckets for all seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like the [Boost Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) library:

> Boost.Accumulators is both a library for incremental statistical
>   computation as well as an extensible framework for incremental
>   calculation in general. The library deals primarily with the concept
>   of an accumulator, which is a primitive computational entity that
>   accepts data one sample at a time and maintains some internal state.
>   These accumulators may offload some of their computations on other
>   accumulators, on which they depend. Accumulators are grouped within an
>   accumulator set. Boost.Accumulators resolves the inter-dependencies
>   between accumulators in a set and ensures that accumulators are
>   processed in the proper order.

Comment: Thanks was looking for ideas for the data structures. Will check out the lib what they use.